# How to retrieve a specific mailchip list by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

I'm very new to both rails and mailchip. I'm able to retrieve all my lists inside my controller with the below code

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @email = Email.new
    @gbList = Gibbon::API.lists.list
    puts "@gbList", @gbList
  end

end
```

I can see all my lists in my console. What I'm trying to do is retrieve one of those lists via the name attribute. For example my list is called "My eList" 
I tried doing:

```
@eList = Gibbon::API.lists.list(:list_name => "My eList");
```

But this still returns an array of all my lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `list_name` key-value pair as a member of the `filters` hash. See the [Gibbon documentation](https://github.com/amro/gibbon#fetching-lists) on *Fetching Lists* for more info:

```
@eList = Gibbon::API.lists.list({:filters => {:list_name => 'My eList'}})
```

Comment: Thanks Zeantsoi. I did look at the docs but it gave no example and I tried a few different ways. Such a simple concept "example" just like you just did. Thanks again.